# Alternatives to Dun & Bradstreet for identifying companies and their relationships?

Tags: web-services, cloud-service

As far as I know, Dun & Bradstreet can identify companies by its name, address and some other attributes, and then provide its firmographics and possibly relationships to its parent company and peer subsidiaries.

Are there alternatives to D&B to provide this service both manually and  programtically?

Comment: Could you please explain what you don't like about D&B, and recenter your question on software? (this site is about software) By the way, if you are looking for Open Data, http://opendata.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask :-)

Comment: I am interested in any web services/APIs that can do this programatically other than D&B, so is this what's covered by this site?

I just want to exercise my due diligence to survey the whole field before committing to one vendor software solution.

I assume Open Data is for free public data/services, so I suspect there is such value-added data and services provided by D&B and other for-profit companies.  Is my understanding correct?

Finally, is there a way to edit my original question to make all these more clear?  (newbie here, still could not find the Edit button for the question...)